# Make a C++ initializer automatically detect union member?

Tags: c++, initialization

OK, the standard still says that brace-initializing a union initializes only the first member.  I suppose this puts this question more in the "Wouldn't it be nice if...?" category.

Does it have to be this way? After all, we now have automatic type detection for other types.

```
auto x = 3; // int
auto s = "foo"; // char *
auto w = L"Foo"; // wchar_t *
```

So why not with a union? Given:

```
struct init 
{
 int t;
 union {
   long long x;
   char *s;
   wchar_t *w;
 };
};
```

Currently you can only brace-initialize `init::x` (with an `int`), not `s` or `w`.

Automatic type detection might be extended so that the union member initialized is selected based on the type of the initializer:

```
auto init initial_data [] = {
 { 0, 3 },      // initializes x, brace elision
 { 1, "foo" },  // initializes s 
 { 2, L"Foo" }  // initializes w
};
```

(of course, this should not compile in the current standard.)

This would make it possible to put all of the `initial_data` in a single initializer list. (I suspect the auto keyword would have to go somewhere else).

Is there something making this a Bad Idea (beyond "nobody's thought of it yet" or "it's too hard to implement")?  Currently you have to do something horrendous like:

```
#define RI(X) reinterpret_cast<long long>(X)
const init initial_data[] = {
{ 0, 3 },      // initializes x, brace elision
{ 1, RI("foo") },  // initializes s 
{ 2, RI(L"Foo") }  // initializes w
};
```

I wouldn't want to go through these contortions, except that a `std::exception` must be initialized with a `std::string` (i.e. based on `char`), so I can't just have an initializer list with all `wchar_t*`.  And I'd really like all of those initializers in the same place.

Comment: `boost::variant` has this behaviour (by and large; beware of ambiguous constructor overloads between variant element types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Update**

In my introduction I mentioned:

> *(though A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors)*

I just realized this enables you to write the required constructors yourself!

```
struct init {
    init(long    long   v) : t(type::longlong), x(v) {}
    init(char    const* v) : t(type::pcsz),     s(v) {}
    init(wchar_t const* v) : t(type::pwcsz),    w(v) {}

    enum class type { longlong, pcsz, pwcsz } t;
    union { long long x; char const* s; wchar_t const* w; };
};
```

Now this compiles:

```
init initial_data [] = {
    3 ,      // initializes x, brace elision
    "foo" ,  // initializes s 
    L"Foo"   // initializes w
};
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/017ee55f044baf10)**

---

> Q. Is there something making this a Bad Idea (beyond "nobody's thought of it yet" or "it's too hard to implement")

In general `union` are very often a bad idea. It's hard to use them safely. In this respect they're a bit "second class" citizens in C++ (though A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual functions, these days).

Letting the compiler select "the" slot to receive the initializer is likely to run into ambiguities very soon.

With brace initialization, they could add some restrictions (no narrowing/widening conversions) like there already are with initializer lists in C++11.

But this is all fantasy. The short of it is: ***this is not a language feature***.

---

`boost::variant` has this behaviour.

Notes

- the `which()` member is basically your type discriminator (`t`)
- you can optimize for size: `BOOST_VARIANT_MINIMIZE_SIZE`
- you should make the char/wchar_t pointers `const*` if you want to assign from a literal!

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5156911283fdab71)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_VARIANT_MINIMIZE_SIZE
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using init = boost::variant<long long, char const*, wchar_t const*>;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    init initial_data [] = {
        3 ,      // initializes x, brace elision
        "foo" ,  // initializes s 
        L"Foo"   // initializes w
    };

    for(auto& v : initial_data)
        std::cout << v.which() << "\t" << v << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0   3
1   foo
2   0x401f14
```

Comment: `boost::variant` has non-trivial copy constructors and assignment operators, so it's not an aggregate, and thus shouldn't be brace initializable?

Comment: @SpencerSimpson indeed, it's not an aggregate. It's brace initializable under _uniform intialization_, which was introduced in c++11 (though not I removed the braces in the edit. Now it's just using the generic conversion constructor)

Comment: Anyway, it seems like a lot of code just to store some data that's just going to be copied somewhere else, and the question was about whether the language itself should do it.

Comment: @SpencerSimpson "the language _should_ do it" - that makes it off-topic for SO :) I suppose you could code up something with recursive bases - still no POD, but could easily be a trivial type. I'd always chose ready-made library over home-brewn solutions here. Note that `variant` has been proposed for c++ standardization (don't know the status, though `optional<>` has made it AFAIR)

Comment: The initial post was with a really simplified example.  The struct in the real code contains several data members and a char* OR a wchar_t*, the choice of which is done differently from a type discriminator member such as in the example.   It would always be wchar_t* except for that silly std::exception constructor.   I'll stick with having two different initializer structs for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67938/discussion-between-spencer-simpson-and-sehe).

Comment: @SpencerSimpson Oops. I just had a brainwave. Turns out I was sitting on the answer. I've just updated my answer to show it.

Comment: I think your answer shows that the feature I was talking about is not necessary -- I just didn't know enough about the new features of C++11.   Just write the constructors you need and brace-initialize to your heart's content.